# Can't surround first concatenated string in Azure pipeline variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

When I have the following structure, it works as expected, producing *onemonkeynotdonkey*

```
variables:
  a: "monkey"
  b: "donkey"
  c: one$(a)"not"$(b)
```

Thinking that I **may** want to add colon or other special character, I wanted to surround the first string with quotes like this.

```
variables:
  a: "monkey"
  b: "donkey"
  c: "one"$(a)"not"$(b)
```

This fails telling me the following.

> While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.

I've been googling the whole day without finding info on this specific syntax. What is it that the computer thinks I'm telling it to do? Also, practically, how do I add the quotations for the first string?

Comment: Just wrap the entire expression in quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need quote at all:
`a: "monkey"` is equivalent to `a: 'monkey'` also equivalent to `a: monkey`.

Depending on the OS and command line tool, you will have to escape special characters differently:

```yaml
variables:
  a: monkey
  b: donkey
  c: one$(a)not$(b)
  d: "one$(a)not$(b)"
  e: 'one$(a)not$(b)'
  f: one$(a), with $p'cial\ not$(b)

steps:
- checkout: none
- script: |
    echo $(c)
    echo $(d)
    echo $(e)

- bash: |
    echo "$(f)"
  env:
    p: p is an env variable

- pwsh: |
    $p = "p is a local variable"
    echo "$(f)"
```